# Coffeescript copy the JSON object with selected keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have the following JSON Object which I want to copy/clone.
While cloning I want only a few specific keys, say id, measurement_tag_id and unit.

Following is my JSON object:

```
{
    "id": 246,
    "measurement_profile_id": 52,
    "measurement_tag_id": 339,
    "unit": "in",
    "value": 5,
    "measurement_tag": {
        "id": 339,
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...many more keys...
}
```

How can I achieve this in coffeescript, using only one liners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple to do with a for loop:

```
new_object = {}
new_object[key] = old_object[key] for key in ["id", "measurement_tag_id", "unit"]
```